# Is it possible to find all matching string form SSRS Report data?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

The user enter the searching word in a text box and   and all the strings that contains the search text needs to be highlighted with a color.

Comment: Could you check out the https://www.gpug.com/blogs/aaron-back/2015/02/23/ssrs-highlight-text-inside-text-field this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the entire string to be highlighted then you can simply set the `BackgroundColor` property of the textbox to be something like..

The assumes you have a parameter called `search`

```
=IIF(Fields!myStringColumn.Value.ToString().Contains(Parameters!search.Value) , "Yellow", Nothing)
```